# How to get all sequinces with tf.keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array and sampling_rate > 1? There are lost last values

Tags: python, dataframe, tensorflow, keras, time-series

I have pd DataFrame with data columns and category column. I want to create Dataset to use in NN.
I'm using code from tensorflow tutorials https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series?hl=ru
Problem: last value isn't what i expected. From this df we can create more sequences!
Why two more sequences weren't created by timeseries_dataset_from_array?
How I can fix it (better with timeseries_dataset_from_array)?

df:

```
arr100_cat = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(100)*10, columns=['range_100'])
arr100_cat['category'] = 0
arr100_cat.loc[arr100_cat.index % 3 == 1, 'category'] = 1
arr100_cat.loc[arr100_cat.index % 3 == 2, 'category'] = 2

    range_100   category
 0  0           0
 1  10          1
 2  20          2
 3  30          0
 4  40          1

input_width = 5
label_width = 3
timeseries_dataset = tf.keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
    arr100_cat.to_numpy(),
    targets=None,
    sequence_length=input_width+label_width,
    sequence_stride=1,
    sampling_rate=3,
    batch_size=1,
    shuffle=False,
    seed=None,
    start_index=None,
    end_index=None
)
```

Itterate Dataset:

```
timeseries_dataset_iter = iter(timeseries_dataset)
for i in range(100):
    timeseries_dataset_next = next(timeseries_dataset_iter)
    print(timeseries_dataset_next)
```

last outputs:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[[750   0]
  [780   0]
  [810   0]
  [840   0]
  [870   0]
  [900   0]
  [930   0]
  [960   0]]], shape=(1, 8, 2), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor(
[[[760   1]
  [790   1]
  [820   1]
  [850   1]
  [880   1]
  [910   1]
  [940   1]
  [970   1]]], shape=(1, 8, 2), dtype=int64)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OutOfRangeError
```

Answer (score 0):

I find solution with window. Window doesn't lose last values as timeseries_dataset_from_array! What's wrong with timeseries_dataset_from_array?

```
batch_size = 2
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    arr100_cat.to_numpy()).window(input_width+label_width, shift=1, stride=3, drop_remainder=True
)
dataset = dataset.flat_map(lambda window: window.batch(input_width+label_width))
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
labels = dataset.map(lambda window: window[:, -label_width:, :])
print([i for i in dataset][-2:])
[<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 3, 2), dtype=int64, numpy=
 array([[[910,   1],
         [940,   1],
         [970,   1]],
 
        [[920,   2],
         [950,   2],
         [980,   2]]], dtype=int64)>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 3, 2), dtype=int64, numpy=
 array([[[930,   0],
         [960,   0],
         [990,   0]]], dtype=int64)>]
```